# Route[login] not defined even after creating custom middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to test an endpoint I built in Laravel based on a tutorial I followed on how to build a JSON API using Laravel.

I would like to carry out a `GET` request to this endpoint. However, whenever I try this I get the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined
```

After searching around I found that I had to create a custom middleware to handle authentication. Now I get this error, even when I do a `GET` request with the api_key associated with this app ie:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tasks?api_token=***`

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

This is my middleware:

```
class CheckApiToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!in_array($request->headers->get('accept'), ['application/json', 'Application/Json']))
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is what I have in kernel.php:

```
'api' => [
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckApiToken::class,
        ],
```

This is the code I have in Models-> task:

```
class Task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ["title"];

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function assignees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the code for my routes:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

JsonApiRoute::server('v1')
    ->prefix('v1')
    ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1')
    ->resources(function ($server) {

        $server->resource('users')
            ->parameter('id')
            ->relationships(function ($relationships) {
                $relationships->hasMany('tasks');
            });

        $server->resource('tasks')
            ->parameter('id')
            ->relationships(function ($relationships) {
                $relationships->hasMany('assignees');
                $relationships->hasOne('creator');
            });

    });
```

and Authenticate middleware:

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
    {
        return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your middleware actually doing? it is only checking the 'accept' header it isn't doing anything related to authentication ...  what route are you hitting when you are getting the `login` route not defined issue? what headers are you sending with the request? what middleware is assigned to that route? the redirect to `login` is usually done via the exception handler handing an AuthenticationException and there are not the correct headers to receive JSON

Comment: @lagbox To answer your questions:
1.) I am hitting this route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tasks` - I have added my routes code to the question
2.) I am sending `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: */*`
3.) I added my Authenticate middleware to the question too

Comment: @lagbox I also tried sending with the header `Accept: application/vnd.api+json`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should pass `Accept` header with value `application/json` in every API request.

But you can set the same in the middleware if you want to force json response always.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Reference: https://dev.to/arxeiss/force-json-response-on-all-api-routes-in-laravel-29h

Comment: Getting the error:  ` "message": "The requested resource is capable of generating only content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.",
`

Sending the request with the headers: `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/vnd.api+json`